# How to debug/diagnose RSS feed that's not working?

Tags: rss

The RSS feeds on my site don't seem to functioning properly. I recently updated my theme to a new theme I developed and ever since that point the RSS feeds don't display all of my site's content properly. My rss feed only displays the Title with link and published date. No featured image or excerpt/body copy.

I have the following in my functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
```

What are some other areas I should investigate on my site?

Comment: Define "not properly"? Do they give 503 errors? Missing information? Redirects? Whitescreen of death? Incorrect information? Please ellaborate

Comment: It only displays the link to the headline and date. No featured image or excerpt/body copy.

Comment: What server are you using (Apache, Nginx, etc.)? Does your site use rewrite rules for permalinks?

Also, what's the URL to your site?  We might be able to to see what's happening directly and assist better.

Comment: @Christiaan Yes! I am using an Nginx server. I think this could be it! It could be some .htaccess stuff. The site is thetechblock.com

Comment: Bear in mind Nginx doesn't use .htaccess, so anything that shows up in that file won't make any difference to the server.  Can you paste your site's `server` configuration in your original question?

Comment: @Christiaan - I suppose then my server is Apache as it's definitely utilizing .htaccess

Comment: It will not be rewrite rules, else it wouldn't work on any theme, not a specific theme. I'm afraid we still dont have enough information to diagnose the problem. At the very least post code, or point us to where we can find the theme. header.php would be a start

Comment: @TomJNowell good point.